# Get whole string if part matches regex

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, jwt

Hi there how can i get the whole string if part matches in regex.
For example i've url https://test-url.com/token-refresh. Now i'm searching for a part of url token-refresh. But it returns only token-refresh. So i could search the whole url, but sometimes url is dynamic, and need to search by the part.
This is for angular jwt, blacklistedUrl.

```
blacklistedRoutes: [
      new RegExp('token-refresh')
]
```

```js
var str = "https://test-url.com/api/v1/token-refresh";
  var patt = new RegExp("token-refresh");
  var res = patt.exec(str);
  alert(res)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a short function to check whether a URL is blacklisted based on the regexes in `blacklistedRoutes` and then use that to control display of the URL (or anything else you want to do with it):

```js
let JWT = {
  blacklistedRoutes: [
    new RegExp('token-refresh')
  ]
};

let isBlacklisted = (str) => JWT.blacklistedRoutes.reduce((c, r) => c || r.test(str), false);

let str = [
  "https://test-url.com/api/v1/token-refresh",
  "https://example.com/should-be-ok"
];

str.map(s =>
  console.log(s + (isBlacklisted(s) ? ' is blacklisted' : ' is ok'))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `exec`, you can test regex using `test`, to solve this issue
Please find below code snippet for solution:

```js
var str = "https://test-url.com/api/v1/token-refresh";
  var patt = new RegExp("token-refresh");
  var res = patt.test(str);
  res ? alert(str) : alert('not matching urp param');
```

Comment: i've forget to mention, it's an library config. JWT.                                   
blacklistedRoutes: [
   new RegExp('token-refresh')                                                                                          
 ]

Comment: @KhujandNanocoding 'test' will work everywhere, and in case of dynamic url / Regex, you can simply replace hardcoded values todynamic values